# Guzzle request POST data to laravel API project ($request->getContent() but the result is empty)

Tags: php, laravel, request, guzzle

I have two project separated:
1. Laravel for user Key-in Data
2. Laravel for API

(1.) Laravel for user Key-in Data work fine in local machine send Data to (2.) but on server not send body's data.

(1.) Key-in Data Project

```php
$client = new Client(['headers' => ['X-Client-Code' => env('KEY_CODE')]]);

$request_param = [
            'client_id'    => $patient->client_id,
            'code'         => $request->code,
            'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
            'sms_type'     => 'card'
        ];
$request_data = json_encode($request_param);
$res = $client->request(
            'POST',
            url(env('API_URL').'api/v0/user/activate-card'),
            [
                'headers' => [
                    'Accept'     => 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' => file_get_contents(storage_path('credential').'/.token')

                ],
                'body'   => $request_data
            ]
        );
return $res->getBody()->getContents();
```

(2.) Laravel API

```php
$ehealth_code = $request->headers->get('x-client-code');
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(),true); // return empty
```

Comment: I loaded `use GuzzleHttp\Client;` above already.

Answer (score 0):

Woops! now it's properly work fine, I just removed `\n` from `file_get_contents(storage_path('credential').'/.token')`. `\n` was contained with string that read from `file/.token`. It's so seriously.

Anyway thanks!!